# Как импортировать функцию из другой папки

Tags: python

Мой проект имеет следующую структуру:

```
Project1
        dev
           test.py
        main.py
```

В файле test.py есть функция get_summa(), которую мне надо импортировать в файл main.py.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно импортировать нужную функцию из другой папки

Comment: А вы пробовали обратиться к функции: `from test import get_summa`, разве не работает?

Comment: пробовала, возникает ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'get_summa' from 'test' (unknown location)

Comment: Можно всё в одну папку поместить, тогда точно будет работать.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы была именно такая структура проекта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from dev.test import get_summa
```

Comment: возникает ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dev.test

Comment: Если файл main действительно находится в директории Project1 - должно работать. Вы не ошиблись с описанием структуры? Какой IDE пользуетесь?

Comment: PyCharm Professional Edition

Comment: Можно попробовать обратиться к функции через импорт всего файла. Попробуйте `from dev import test`. А в main.py вызвать функцию `test.get_summa()`

Comment: теперь получилось. Спасибо большое!